# is &a[i] and &a[i-1]+sizeof(int) same if a is integer array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to know whether &a[i] and &a[i-1]+sizeof(int) print the same value of address?
When i printed values it came different.How is it ? eg.say a[0] is at 1000 and a[1] at 1002 , then both a[1] and &a[i-1]+sizeof(int) where i=1 should return same right?

code snippet:

```
{
   int a[3]={100,200,300};
   print &a[1] and print &a[0]+sizeof(int)
}
```

Comment: I think I understand the question but it's not clear, add some sample code plese.

Comment: he asks if it is continously mapped on ram on any case

Comment: `&a[i-1]+sizeof(int)` --> `&a[i-1]+1`

Comment: I think the OP means `int a;`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `&a[i-1]+sizeof(int)` --> `&a[i-1]+1` would only be true if `sizeof(int)` equals `1`.

Comment: @chux see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/mdwafy)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  The posted comment `&a[i-1]+sizeof(int) --> &a[i-1]+1` differs from the demo. `(void*)&a[1], (void*)(&a[0] + 1)`

Comment: @chux `(void*)` for `%p`. Address itself does not change.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The `(void *)` is not the issue.  The comment "`&a[i-1]+sizeof(int)` --> `&a[i-1]+1`" is the same as "`some_int_pointer + sizeof(int)` --> `some_int_pointer + 1`".  Rarely is the `sizeof(int) == 1`, more like 2, 4, or 8.  So the comment becomes "`some_int_pointer + 4` --> `some_int_pointer + 1`" which is certainly incorrect.

Comment: @chux You're misunderstanding my comment. OP there is the assumption that the same address by plus the offset. So I was instructed to offset in pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68182/discussion-between-chux-and-bluepixy).

Comment: I'm busy so I'll leave the refrain.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is of type array and `&a` is of type pointer. *Their types are not the same*.

This `&a+1` is pointer arithmetic. Increasing the `&a` by 1 will take you to last position + 1 in the array. Example (assuming `size` is 5):

```
   |0|1|2|3|4| |
   a^         ^
          &a+1^
```

The type of `a` is `int[size]` (for e.g.) that decays into address of first element in expression `a + 1`, adding one  results points to second element in `a`; whereas type of `&a` is `int(*)[size]`.

Stressing again **their types are not the same**. The type of pointer determines where you land next in memory, theoretically its something like:

```
address2 = BlockAddress + sizeof(TYPE)*IncrementVal
```

Comment: @mahashwetha - its `i` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. On several machines, `sizeof(int)` is 4. `&a[i-1]+sizeof(int)` is `&a[i-1]+4` which is `&a[i+3]` i.e. `a+i+3`

The addition on pointers (i.e. `p+n` where `p` is a pointer -or an array- and `n` is an integer) works in units of the type referenced by `p`. So if `p` points to a `struct` of 1024 bytes, `p+1` has an address 1024 greater than `p`